# ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI getting deleted contacts

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

** Edit**

This is the URI in question: ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI

Is there any way of knowing if a contact is marked for deletion from this URI?

I already tried querying for the DELETED column, but it crashes with an SQL exception

Thanks for your help

** Attached code **

```
ContentQuery contentQuery = new ContentQuery(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .column(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID)
            .column(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)
            .column(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)
            .column(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LOOKUP_KEY)
            .column(CommonDataKinds.Note.NOTE)
            .column(Data.MIMETYPE)
            .column(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.STARRED)
            .where(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DELETED, "=", "1");
```

Where ContentQuery is a query builder interface

Comment: `of knowing if a contact is marked for deletion from this URI?`. ??? Where is this about? I see no contract. I see no uri.

Comment: Please see the title, but I will add it to the description itself :)

Comment: adding the `RawContacts.DELETED` field to your projection should work, as you can have implicit joins from the RawContacts table, specifically `DELETED` is mentioned as working. show your code

Comment: I'm pretty sure the reason for the DELETED table is because of that. Added in the edit

Comment: Hey have you been able to solve it ? I am also getting the same thing . Deleted contact with no numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but to get the implicit join of the `DELETED` field from `RawContacts` [as mentioned in the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html), you need to add `RawContacts.DELETED` to your projection.

Check the following code, it should print data belonging to deleted contacts:

```
String[] projection = new String[] { Phone.CONTACT_ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER, RawContact.DELETED };
Cursor cur = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, null ,null, null);
while (cur.moveToNext()) {
    if (cur.getInt(3) == 1) {
        Log.i("TAG", "found a deleted data row: " + cur.getLong(0) + ", " + cur.getString(1) + ", " + cur.getString(2));
    }
}
cur.close();
```

Comment: using Data.CONTENT_URI and adding projection to RawContact.DELETED throws column not found exception